# php mysql Select year with parameter

Tags: php, mysql, date

Struggling with the following code which is not working ($ThisYear paramater)

```
$ThisYear = date("Y"); 
$ThisYear = strtotime($ThisYear);
$sql2 = 'SELECT 
            distinct 
            DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") as MonthYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%Y") as TransYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%m") as TransMonth 
        from Leave 
        where YEAR(TransDate) = **"$ThisYear"**  
        group by DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") 
        order BY YEAR(TransDate), MONTH(TransDate) desc';
```

versus this which is working:

```
$ThisYear = date("Y"); 
$sql2 = 'SELECT 
            distinct 
            DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") as MonthYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%Y") as TransYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%m") as TransMonth 
        from Leave 
        where YEAR(TransDate) = **2022** 
        group by DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") 
        order BY YEAR(TransDate), MONTH(TransDate) desc';
```

Comment: So try `where YEAR(TransDate) =  $ThisYear` except you should be trying to avoid! [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: You could also do `WHERE YEAR(TransDate) = YEAR(curdate())` and not need to use a PHP variable at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PHP documentation, **[strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** parse about any English textual datetime description into a **Unix timestamp**.

In order:

- Your variable was converted into a number (1666484520 Unix timestamp for 2022).
- Server compared the number of the year to your variable = 1666484520.

That's the right query and variable.

```
$ThisYear = date("Y"); 
$sql2 = 'SELECT 
            distinct 
            DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") as MonthYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%Y") as TransYear
            , DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%m") as TransMonth 
        from Leave 
        where YEAR(TransDate) = $ThisYear 
        group by DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, "%M %Y") 
        order BY YEAR(TransDate), MONTH(TransDate) desc';
```